# Unable to launch Android application in Eclipse through Testdroid recorder

Tags: eclipse, junit, robotium, recorder, testdroid

Unable to launch Android application in Eclipse through Testdroid recorder; 
Below mentioned error occured:

"An internal error occurred during: "com.bitbar.testdroid". junit/framework/Test”.

Comment: post some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Changes required in Android configure build path.

**Actions:** source project > right click > build path > configure build path > android, then Remove library and add again same library which is already add with error.